# Adding translation support to spinner

Tags: java, android, language-translation

I have a spinner of strings. I want to add support to multi langues so I move the strings into `strings.xml` file and now I have the following method in consts class:

```
    public static String[] getCars(Activity activity) {
        if (activity == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return new String[] {
                activity.getString(R.string.car1),
                activity.getString(R.string.car2)
                // more
        };
    }
```

Now I display the cars in the spinner as follows:

```
        Spinner spinner = findViewById(spinnerId);
        ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerValues);
        spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
```

Other code to handle changes:

```
        String car = shift.getCar(); // from DB
        int carPosition = Arrays.asList(ShiftUtils.getCars(this)).indexOf(car);
        Spinner carsSpinner = findViewById(R.id.add_car_spinner);
        carsSpinner.setSelection(carPosition);
```

I keep the car names in English in the DB so `getCar()` will return the chosen car name in English. But then if my application is currently in other language, `carPosition` will be `-1` because it will not find the string (because `car` is in English). I want to display the spinner values to be in the locale language but in the background (fetch and push) to be in English. What would be the best way to do it? I prefer not to touch the DB (keep it in English).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getting the car name from your DB, create a unique ID for each car, and make your spinner item list hold both the ids and the text values.

This way, you'll be able to get the id of the selected car from the DB, and set it as the selected car in your spinner, regardless of the display language